# How do I shut down node app.js & in Putty

Tags: node.js, putty

I am using Putty. I used `node app.js &` to keep the server running even after I closed Putty. Now, after reopening Putty, I cannot figure out how to stop the server from running. What command should I use in this situation?

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Please, can you share with us some more details? I.e.: which os mounts the machine you connect to? It's a Linux-based machine? Do you have admin privileges?

Comment: Like @MatteoMeil said we need more info but on linux based systems you can use `screen`. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I use Linux and pkill worked for me. I'll look into screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on which OS nodejs is running.

For Linux based you can use `pkill`:

```sh
pkill node
```

For Windows based:

```
taskkill /im node.exe
```

Both commands kill all running nodejs instances.